# Find $y$ which satisfies: $y'=y^a$, $y(a)=a-2$, for $a \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'd love your help with finding the function $y$ which satisfies: $y'=y^a$, $y(a)=a-2$, for $a \in \mathbb{N}$

This is what I did:

$$\begin{align*}
\int \frac{y'}{y^a}dx&=\int 1dx\\
\frac{y^{-a+1}}{-a+1}+c_1&=x+c_2\\
y^{-a+1}&=(x+C)(-a+1),
\end{align*}$$
where $C=c_2-c_1$, and for $a=1$ there's no solution.

So I get 
$$y=\left(\frac{1}{(x+c)(1-a)}\right)^{a-1},$$ 
finding $c$ is not pleasant.

I assume that something is wrong, Am I suppose leave $y$ in the way that I find it after finding $c$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Shouldn't your general solution for $a\ne1$ be $y=((x+c)(1-a))^{1/(1-a)}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong, except abandoning poor $a=1$, which though a little special gives no problems. When we do the details we will see there *is* a problem at $a=2$.

Quite quickly (for $a\ne 1$) we reach
$$\frac{y^{-a+1}}{-a+1}=x+C.$$
It is best to find $C$ *now*. Put $x=a$. We get 
$$\frac{(a-2)^{-a+1}}{-a+1}=a+C.$$
Now we know $C$, except when $a=2$ (one cannot divide by $0$).  So for $a=2$ there is no solution that satisfies the initial  condition.

There is no trouble if $a=1$. True, the above general formula does not quite work. But if we integrate, we get
$$\ln(|y|)=x+C.$$
Put $x=1$. We can now solve for $C$, and end up with $y=-e^{x-1}$.  Alternately, we end up with $y=C'e^x$, and conclude that $C'=-e^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How do you get the equation with $\ln$ for $a=1$? Don't we get $y^0=0$ which leads us to no solution for this case?

Comment: Remember from early integration that $\int \frac{dt}{t}=\ln(|t|)+C$.  The case $k=-1$ is the only exception to the general formula for $\int t^k\,dt$.

Comment: Right, I missed it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I presume for each $a$ your need to find one function $y_a$.

Your working seems essentially correct, but you can re-write as

$$\frac{1}{(1-a)y^{a-1}}  -x = C$$

Plug in the required values of $x$ and $y$ and find $C$.